# Managing dependencies in Angular JS karma grunt testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, gruntjs, karma-runner

My controller :

```
/**
 * @description
 * Controller for Comparative Analysis dashboard.
 */

(function (define) {

    define([], function () {

        /**
      * Constructor function.
      *
      * @param {Object} $scope Object that binds model to view.
      * @param {Object} $log object(angular service) to log info,waring and error messages.     
      *

      */
        //var caDashboardController = function ($scope, $log, configService, caCommonService, caConsumptionChartService) {
        var caDashboardController = function ($scope, $log) {




   }
        return ["$scope", "$log", caDashboardController];

    });


})(define);
```

My Module :

```
(function (define, angular) {

    'user strict'

    define([

        'myAnalytics/comparativeAnalysis/dashboard/controllers/caDashboardController',

        ], function (caDashboardController) {


        var moduleName = "AnalyticsApp.comparativeAnalysis";

        angular.module(moduleName, ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'kendo.directives'])
        .config(['$routeProvider', function config($routeProvider) {

            $routeProvider.when('/comparativeAnalysis', {
                controller: 'caDashboardController',
                templateUrl: 'app/myAnalytics/comparativeAnalysis/dashboard/comparativeAnalysisdashboard.html'
            });

        }])
            .controller("caDashboardController", caDashboardController);


        return moduleName;
    });


})(define, angular);
```

My Unit test case Spec :

```
(function (define) {
    'use strict';

    define([
        'kendo',
        'angularRoute',
        'angularResource',
        'moment',
        'myAnalytics/comparativeAnalysis/dashboard/comparativeAnalysisModule'
    ],
    function () {

        describe('Test for comparative Analysis Dashboard Controller', function () {



              var scopeMock, logMock, ctrl, configServiceMock, caCommonServiceMock, caConsumptionChartServiceMock;

                var serviceResponse = null;

                var deferredCompareResult;

                beforeEach(module('AnalyticsApp.comparativeAnalysis'));

                beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $log, caCommonService, caConsumptionChartService) {
                    scopeMock = $rootScope.$new();
                    logMock = $log;

                    //configServiceMock = { comparativeAnalysisUrl: '/COMPARATIVEANALYSISURL/' };
                    configServiceMock = { csrServiceUrl: '/CSRSERVICEURL/' };//$injector.get('configService');
                    caCommonServiceMock = caCommonService;
                    caConsumptionChartServiceMock = caConsumptionChartService;
                }));

                describe('Successful Server response tests', function () {

                    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $q) {

                        deferredCompareResult = $q.defer();
                        deferredCompareResult.resolve(serviceResponse);

                        //spyOn(caCommonServiceMock, 'getData').and.returnValue(deferredCompareResult.promise);
                        //spyOn(caConsumptionChartServiceMock, 'getChartData').and.returnValue(deferredCompareResult.promise);

                        ctrl = $controller('caDashboardController',
                        {
                            '$scope': scopeMock,
                            '$log': logMock
                            //'configService': configServiceMock
                            //'caCommonService' :caCommonServiceMock,
                            //'caConsumptionChartService': caConsumptionChartServiceMock
                        });

                    }));

                    it('$scope should be configured', function () {
                        expect(ctrl).toBeDefined();
                    });

                    it('Consumption Graph Data should be set', inject(function ($rootScope) {
                        //expect(ctrl).toBeDefined();
                        //expect(scopeMock.caViewModel.chartData).toBeDefined();
                        ////scopeMock.caViewModel.search('');
                        //expect(caConsumptionChartServiceMock.getChartData).toHaveBeenCalled();
                        //$rootScope.$apply();
                        //expect(scopeMock.caViewModel.chartData).toBe(null);
                    }));

                });
            });
        });
    })(define);
```

In Ctrl I am just referring `'$scope'` and `'$log'` --

```
ctrl = $controller('caDashboardController',
                    {
                        '$scope': scopeMock,
                        '$log': logMock
                        //'configService': configServiceMock
                        //'caCommonService' :caCommonServiceMock,
                        //'caConsumptionChartService': caConsumptionChartServiceMock
                    });
```

I am getting few errors ;

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: configServiceProvider <- configService <- caCommonService

Error: Declaration Location

Error: Expected undefined to be defined.
```

Please help me How I can configure this. As you can see I am not using anything in my Controller. Its almost empty, But still I am getting this errors..
I have no reference for `configService` But error is related to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function (define) {
    'use strict';

    define([
        'kendo',
        'angularRoute',
        'angularResource',
        'myAnalytics/comparativeAnalysis/dashboard/services/caCommomService',
        'myAnalytics/comparativeAnalysis/dashboard/services/caConsumptionChartServic',
        'myAnalytics/comparativeAnalysis/dashboard/controllers/caDashboardController', 
    ],

    function (moment,caCommomService,caConsumptionChartServic,caDashboardController) {
        var abcController;
        beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope,$controller, $q, $timeout) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();  
            q = $q;
            timeout = $timeout;
            abcController = $controller(caDashboardController, {
                $scope: scope,
                abcService: caConsumptionChartServic         
            });
    }));
    // you are using requirejs dependencies so try to pass direct files and use no to get main module.
}
```

Comment: can you check by debug the spec file via chrome check "caDashboardController" params or console.log

Comment: can you check the relative path is correct or not let me know if you still see same error